# Serializing JSON value having Bigint

Tags: pg-promise

I have a JSON value as a parameter to one of my query, This parameter contains Bigint inside the JSON internally pg-promise uses `JSON.stringfy() on line 80 utils.js for 10.7.1 version` which would break, i am fixing this by adding

```
  return JSON.stringify(val, (key, value) =>
    typeof value === 'bigint'
      ? value.toString()
      : value // return everything else unchanged
  );
```

is there any other way for this?

Adding code for completion:

```
 payloads = [{ "d": 1n }];
            await this.#writerPG.tx((transaction) => {
                payloads.map((p) => transaction.none(this.#queries.Enqueue, [p]));
                return transaction.batch;
            });
```

Error received:

```
(node:65560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at prepareObject (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/utils.js:80:15)
    at prepareValue (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/utils.js:65:12)
    at prepareValueWrapper (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/utils.js:181:12)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Query.prepare (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:202:35)
    at Query.submit (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:155:12)
    at Client._pulseQueryQueue (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:472:45)
    at Client.query (/Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:567:10)
    at /Users/~/Documents/Git/Personal/pg-queue/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/query.js:156:27
```

Comment: Latest `pg-promise` supports `BigInt` right out of the box. How did you manage to break it? You need to show the actual code. See also [BigInt Manual](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/BigInt).

Comment: Oh this is not bigint as a param its JSON as a param which has bigint inside it...

Comment: I understand, and you need to post the code that causes the problem. Something must be wrong in your code, and we do not know what till you show the code.

Comment: What is `this.#queries.Enqueue`? Is that a Prepared Statement or Parameterized Query?

Comment: Sorry its a prepared statement like below 
INSERT INTO "Abc" ("Payload","Page")
    SELECT $1,2

Comment: Only `pg-promise` knows how to serialize `BigInt`, but when you use a Prepared Statement, the parameters are sent into the server, which doesn't know how to format those, hence the error. I'm not sure it is even possible at all. Anyhow, this is not an issue in `pg-promise`. If you want to investigate further, look at [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres), which throws the error. If you use regular queries, not prepared statements, the error will go away.

Comment: I cannot remember the cause for this, so I've just opened [new issue to chase it](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2395).

Comment: I am sure this is not PG server problem cause its JSON, I realised its PG problem cause utils belongs to them, before i thought utils is part of pg-promise package.. The fix that i did works so its more of pg package problem then servers i think..

Comment: You can just add your own formatter in the meantime: `BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString()  }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: serialize BigInt in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152373/typescript-serialize-bigint-in-json)