# TypeScript: serialize BigInt in JSON

Tags: json, typescript, global, bigint

I'm looking for a way to force `JSON.stringify` to always print `BigInt`s without complaining.

I know it's non-standard, I know there's a package for that in pure JavaScript; but it doesn't fit my needs. I even know a fix in raw JavaScript by setting `BigInt.prototype.toJSON`. What I need is some way to override the normal `JSON.stringify` function globally in my TypeScript code.

I had found the following code, a year or so ago:

```js
declare global
{
    interface BigIntConstructor
    {
        toJSON:()=>BigInt;
    }
}

BigInt.toJSON = function() { return this.toString(); };
```

on some web page I can't manage to find again. It used to work in another project of mine, but it doesn't seem to work any more. I have no idea why.

No matter what I do to the lines above, if I try to print a JSON containing a BigInt, I get: `TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt`.

Any help is appreciated - many thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't `toJSON:()=>BigInt` be `toJSON:(num: BigInt)=>string`?

Comment: Asked myself the very same question when I discovered that code snippet. It didn't work then; it doesn't work now (it's one of the thing I tested as a sanity check...). This code snippet still mystifies me. Btw, I experimented some more, and I think the reason why it doesn't work anymore might be linked to my `tsconfig.json`; but I'm not sure what I'd need to do to have it work again; and if it's even compatible with my current "target" needs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the `replacer` argument for `JSON.stringify` like this:

```
const obj = {
  foo: 'abc',
  bar: 781,
  qux: 9n
}

JSON.stringify(obj, (_, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? v.toString() : v)
```

Comment: Doesn't work - bigints get serialized as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: @riv, you should not serialize bigints as numbers. JSON specification doesn't specify number precision, so in principle something like `'{"foo": 1e1000}'` is valid JSON. But when you parse it, the number is converted to whatever "number" type your platform uses. For JS this is, well, `number` which is finite precision, so this JSON will be parsed as `{foo: Infinity}`. You have to serialize bigints as strings and parse them specifically instead

Answer (score 11):

This is what you looking for:

```
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString() }
```

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-953187833

Comment: This works with pure JavaScript, but not TypeScript. Compiling with tsc gives error TS2339: Property 'toJSON' does not exist on type 'BigInt'.

Comment: There's a TypeScript solution in that link if you keep reading: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-1006088574

Answer (score 6):

## BigInt to JSON in 2024

There is no single correct method to use in every case. As explained by Jakob Kummerow in a [discussion](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-521449285) in a Google Chrome Labs GitHub repository:

> Working as intended/spec'ed: https://tc39.es/proposal-bigint/#sec-serializejsonproperty (step 10).
>
> In short, the background is that JSON is so commonly used among all sorts of different systems and programming languages that it is effectively impossible to add anything to the format without breaking compatibility in some crucial case.
>
> You can define your own .toJSON() function, and pass a corresponding "reviver" function as an argument to JSON.parse(). That way, at least you have control over any (backwards) compatibility issues.

Typescript (and Javascript), by default, will not create a BigInt value when parsing JSON no matter how large the number is. It will parse it as the nearest number, silently ignoring errors with precision.

There are a few ways to work around this, but they depend on you having control over both stringfying *and* parsing the JSON. Otherwise, the JSON you produce may not parse correctly because it violates standards.

Here are a few methods:

### Use strings as a go-between

If you convert your BigInt into a string, it will be parsed as one. However, this may be acceptable when you know which field will be a string. You can just convert it explicitly when you encounter it. To do this, you can modify the prototype of `BigInt` as [described by Holger Jeromin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-1006088574).

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-redeclare
interface BigInt {
    /** Convert to BigInt to string form in JSON.stringify */
    toJSON: () => string;
}
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    return this.toString();
};
```

Or, if you're not using strict Typescript:

```
BigInt.prototype["toJSON"] = function () {
  return this.toString();
};
```

*WARNING*: Modifying the prototype of standard Javascript objects is discouraged for [very good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183678/9035707). If you are publishing a library, PLEASE DO NOT DO IT!

Someone with the paradoxical username noskill24 suggested [a polyfill](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-1306990652) that ensures there is no existing `.toJSON()` before installing it:

```js
// Polyfill: BigInt.prototype.toJSON 

(function(global, undefined) {
  if (global.BigInt.prototype.toJSON === undefined) {
    global.Object.defineProperty(global.BigInt.prototype, "toJSON", {
        value: function() { return this.toString(); },
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true
    });
  }
})(window !== void 0 ? window : typeof global !== void 0 ? global : typeof self !== void 0 ? self : this);
```

### Use numbers as a go-between

Using strings is great, if you know which field hides a BigInt. But what if you don't? You could just convert to a `Number` and let that get serialized as JSON. This method looks exactly like the previous one, except you'll use `Number(this)` instead of `this.toString()`.

*WARNING*: This method has a major flaw. It loses precision. This means the number you receive might be close to the number you sent, but not exactly the same.

### Use an object as a go-between

Another method, although more verbose, is to use an object as a go-between. You can serialize your `BigInt` as an object that contains a field indicating that the object is a `BigInt` and another field holding the value. There is a `bignumberify` library that uses this method. It relies on the fact that [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) accepts a replacer function, and [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) accepts a reviver function, both as an optional second parameter.

The author of that library gives [an example](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/jsbi/issues/30#issuecomment-1542720316) of what a `BigInt` holding `125000n` would serialize as:

```json
{ 
  "type": "BigInt", 
  "hex": "0x01e848"
}
```

Their library relies on a function that must be passed to the `JSON.stringify`:

```
const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj, bigNumberify.stringify);
```

This is great because it avoids potential conflicts with other libraries and future modifications to the standards that are caused by modifying `BigInt`'s prototype.

However, I think an object like that adds bloat while preventing the value from being human-readable (unless you consider hexadecimal to be human-readable). It also eliminates a major benefit of JSON, which is the direct correlation between the structure in JSON and the structure when parsed. A compatible parser will produce a different tree than standard ones would. I prefer a method that maintains the precision of the string method with the convenience of the number method and without the bloat of the object method.

### Use a structured string as a go-between

What I propose is to stringify `BigInt` as a quoted string ending in `n`, which is very similar to the standard way of specifying `BigInt` numbers, making them human-readable and easy to convert automatically. To accomplish this, you need to define a replacer and reviver function:

```
function bigIntReplacer(key: string, value: any): any {
  if (typeof value === "bigint") {
    return value.toString() + 'n';
  }
  return value;
}

function bigIntReviver(key: string, value: any): any {
  if (typeof value === 'string' && /^\d+n$/.test(value)) {
    return BigInt(value.slice(0, -1));
  }
  return value;
}
```

Now you can use these when calling `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` like this:

```
const bigInteger = BigInt(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) * BigInt(8);

// Stringify using the replacer
const jsonBigInteger = JSON.stringify(bigInteger, bigIntReplacer);

// Print JSON to show it is a string
console.log(`As JSON, it is a ${typeof jsonBigInteger} containing: ${jsonBigInteger}`);

// Parse it from JSON
const fromJsonBigInteger = JSON.parse(jsonBigInteger, bigIntReviver);

// Print that number to show it is a bigint
console.log(`After passing through JSON, it is a ${typeof fromJsonBigInteger} containing ${fromJsonBigInteger.toString()}`);
```

No method is perfect, but I hope this has been a good summary of the available options.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to get JSON.stringify to work in one of the dependencies, so I couldn't use the above answer. Instead, I created a patch.js file:

```
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return this.toString()
}
```

Then at the beginning of my TypeScript source I added:

```
require('patch.js')
```

After that, JSON.stringify could handle BigInts without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is a generic issue related to JavaScript's `JSON.stringify()` method.

To solve this problem, create a JavaScript polyfill to solve this problem.

Create a new file in your project and paste this code:

```js
// # for JavaScript
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return this.toString()
}
```

or:

```js
// # for TypeScript
(BigInt.prototype as any).toJSON = function() {
    return this.toString()
}
```

And at the entry point of your project, import this file, ex:

```
// # index.js
import './polyfills.js'

// ... rest of your code
```