# Prisma: TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to fetch data from database and this is my prisma model:

```
  model instant_reports {
  id         BigInt    @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedBigInt
  created_at DateTime?
  updated_at DateTime?
  deleted_at DateTime?
  timestamp  BigInt?
  client_id  BigInt?
  uniq_users BigInt?
}
```

So when i fetch data like this

```
  prismaService.instant_reports.findMany({
      skip: 0,
      take: 30,
    });
```

It throws error

> TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt at JSON.stringify(<anonymous>)

And i don't even know how to deal with it, is there way to change data handler in `findMany` method?

If there is no rows in `instant_reports` so it gives me empty array without error, so the problem is in data with BigInt type

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: serialize BigInt in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65152373/typescript-serialize-bigint-in-json)

Answer (score 11):

It worked for me. Add this code to the beginning of yours.

```js
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function () {
  const int = Number.parseInt(this.toString());
  return int ?? this.toString();
};
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Comment: For NestJS, this needs to be added in bootstrap function in main.ts before app.listen line

Comment: Also, this must be approved as accepted answer since it solves the problem. I have upvoted it.

@bluepuper

Answer (score 3):

## This is the most simple and secure way!!!

## Modifying the prototype is likely to cause problems somewhere.

---

Just copy and paste the simple function below.

```
const json = (param: any): any => {
  return JSON.stringify(
    param,
    (key, value) => (typeof value === "bigint" ? value.toString() : value) // return everything else unchanged
  );
};
export default json;
```

And then you can use like this

```
import json from "../helper/json";

router.get("/", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
    take: 15,
  });
  res.status(200).type("json").send(json(users));
});
```

This is how it works:

Maybe most of us just want to send those Prisma datas in JSON format using ExpressJS.

Whether you are using the library or not, you will inevitably go through `JSON.stringify()` at some point in your code.

Unfortunately, `JSON.stringify()` can't handle BigInt correctly.

So, we all must have to convert BigInt to String if you want to use it.

#### ※ To ExpressJS users

Don't use `res.json()` method!

If you use, you will unintentionally wrap twice like below

`JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(something))`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to deal with this is to avoid your entity id to get into a JSON.stringify function, therefore if you get this from prisma:

```
const user = prisma.user.create({ data: { id: 1, name: "user"})
```

and you use JSON.stringify(user), if user id is a Bigint you are going to get the error.

the solution in this case would be

```
JSON.stringify({...user, id: user.id.toString()})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because JavaScript's JSON.stringify doesn't know how to handle BigInt types. So I should have to create a custom serialiser for BigInt fields before sending them as a response to the client. Like this:

```
function bigIntToString(value) {
  const MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 2 ** 53 - 1;
  return value <= MAX_SAFE_INTEGER ? Number(value) : value.toString();
}

function serializeInstantReports(instantReports) {
  return instantReports.map(report => {
    const newReport = { ...report };
    if (typeof report.id === 'bigint') newReport.id = bigIntToString(report.id);
    // ...
    // such convirtions for other BigInt fields
    // ...
    return newReport;
  });
}
```

And then return from a fetch function result of this `serializeInstantReports`

Answer (score 0):

In cases where third party code is using JSON.stringify and fails on BigInt, for example, when using Prisma and trying to serve back some database object that contains BigInt, you can override JSON.stringify as follow:

```
const overrideJsonBigIntSerialization = (): void => {
  const originalJSONStringify = JSON.stringify
    
  JSON.stringify = function (value: any, replacer, space: number): string {
    const bigIntReplacer = (_key: string, value: any): any => {
      if (typeof value === 'bigint') {
        return parseInt(value.toString())
      }
      return value
    }

    const customReplacer = (key: string, value: any): any => {
      if (Array.isArray(replacer) && !replacer.includes(key) && key !== '') {
        return undefined
      }

      const modifiedValue = bigIntReplacer(key, value)

      if (typeof replacer === 'function') {
        return replacer(key, modifiedValue)
      }
    
      return modifiedValue
    }
  
    return originalJSONStringify(value, replacer != null ? customReplacer : bigIntReplacer, space)
  }
}
```

and in the beginning of your code, call once to `overrideJsonBigIntSerialization()`